# How can I display content of the same type in different ways

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, display-suite

I have some content of the same type already on the site, but there are distinctions within the content, maybe categorized with taxonomy, that sub-type the items. What is a good approach to displaying these sub-types in different ways?

Comment: Your request is vague. You are going to have to be explicit on what you mean by "different ways".

Comment: Interesting question, there would have to be some way to preprocess the taxonomy field before the page is rendered. Almost like a pre-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to generate your theme's template recommendations based on the URL alias of the page you're viewing. For example consider the following example paths:

**car/ferrari/red**

**car/ferrari/black**

**car/bmw/blue**

**car/bmw/red**

The paths above are generated using the following URL path pattern:

**[node:content-type]/[node:field-car-brand-category]/[node:field-car-color-category]**

Now that you've defined the URL paths, you can add this PHP snippet to your template.php either in hook_preprocess_page or hook_preprocess_node, depending on the template type you'd like to add to the suggestions:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) { 

    //get path alias without querying DB manually
    $alias = explode('/',drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri())); 

    //add template suggestions based on path
    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);

    if ($path != $_GET['q']) {
      $template_filename = 'page';

      //Break it down for each piece of the alias path
      foreach (explode('/', $path) as $path_part) {
        $template_filename = $template_filename . '__' . str_replace('-', '_', $path_part);
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $template_filename;
      }
    }
}
```

Now if you examine the var dump for **$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']**, you'll notice a template hierachy based on the current URL path tokens.

This might not be a fool proof way to achieve what you're after, but it is certainly works and is quick and easy.

Comment: That's a great idea, very quick and easy, like you said. Thanks!